# How do you convert UINT8 to UINT32 in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-c++, int, type-conversion

I have a value of type `UINT8` and I would like to make it `UINT32`.

Would my following code be considered correct, valid, efficient and safe?

```
UINT32 convU8toU32(UINT8 *number) {
  UINT32 result = *number;
  return *result;
}
```

Please notice that I'm a new comer to C++ from the Java world.

Comment: Now your code is "correct" (until the `return *result;` which should be `return result;`), but why using a pointer instead of a simple `UINT8`?

Comment: @Holt No reason, I'm experimenting with the language. I thought that would be more efficient with the memory usage.

Comment: @M.A.Kishawy If you are concerned about memory usage, don't replace an 8 bit integer with a 32/64 bit pointer. ;) But one usually need not worry about those amounts of memory "wasted" anyways.

Comment: @M.A.Kishawy The compiler is a much better code generator than you are. Don't think about "memory usage", especially here. Most likely that parameter will end up in a register anyways (or the compiler may just inline it, and if it's really smart it may even just make it a no-op once it looks at how the caller is using it). Plus, on a PC at least, you have gigabytes of memory.

Comment: It's impossible to say without making assumptions. What are the definitions of `UINT8` and `UINT32`?

Comment: @PeteBecker Built-in unsigned integer types with a width of 8 and 32 bits respectively I was bold enough to assume. If that was wrong, please correct me OP.

Comment: @PeteBecker An 8-bit and 32-bit unsigned int, respectively, because we assume a sane world free of conspiracies to trick us. In any case go big or go home, I say: Either don't ask that question, or go all the way and ask things like "Is `return` `#define`d to something goofy somewhere? Please show us the preprocessor output." :P

Comment: @JasonC - there is nothing more perverse than the real world. Engineering should be based on knowledge, not unstated assumptions.

Comment: @PeteBecker I don't know. I think some folks' perception of reality can certainly exceed reality's perverseness sometimes... we could always migrate this question to http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/ though. :D

Comment: I just hope you don't fall in the common pointer trap when switching from Java to C++. Unlike Java modern C++ should use (almost) never `new`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function is correct as is (the typo with the `*` in the `return *result;` aside), but you don't even need it. Integers (and other integral types) convert implicitly to one another, and as `UINT32` can represent every value a `UINT8` can have, you can simply write

```
UINT32 target = source;
```

for some `UINT8 source`.

Making the conversion explicit with a `static_cast` is optional; if the conversion was (potentially) narrowing, the cast would silence some compiler warnings.

Answer (score 4):

You need

```
 UINT32 result = static_cast<UINT32>(*number);
```

to de-refernce the pointer and cast it to the right type

But would

```
UINT32 convU8toU32(UINT8 number) {
   return static_cast<UINT32>(number);
}
```

be better and avoid pointers in the first place

Event better avoid the function call and type in the static cast in the appropriate line of code.

Comment: You don't actually need `static_cast` here. For widening casts it is identical to the implicit cast and just adds verbosity. You may *want* it if you're in to strict C++ philosophical correctness (nothing wrong with that, although I personally dislike the verbosity especially compared to equivalent C style casts) but you do not *need* it. The original assignment with the implicit cast is sufficient and correct.

Comment: *"implicit cast"* s/cast/conversion/, casts are always explicit.

Comment: And there I was thinking that "modern" C++ encourages redundant verbosity :)

Comment: @ddriver C++: [Yo dawg](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/xzibit-yo-dawg), I heard you like templates...

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> UINT32 convU8toU32(UINT8 *number) {
>   UINT32 result = *number;
>   return *result;
> }
> ```

I assume in my answer that `UINT32` and `UINT8` are fancy aliases for fundamental integer types.

> Would my [...] code be considered
>
> - correct, valid

No, given my assumption that `UINT32` is an integer. You cannot dereference an integer. Which is what you try to do on line `return *result;`

> - efficient

Does not matter since it is not correct.

> - safe

Well, it safely fails to compile.

---

This should be OK:

```
UINT32 convU8toU32(UINT8 number) {
    return number;
}
```

Of course, this is so simple that you may want to consider not calling the function, but assign directly in the first place:

```
// not UINT32 foo = convU8toU32(some_uint8);
// but instead:
UINT32 foo = some_uint8;
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, no.   Assuming `UINT32` is a 32-bit unsigned integral type and `UINT8` is an 8-bit unsigned integral type, your code

```
UINT32 convU8toU32(UINT8 *number) {
   UINT32 result = *number;
   return *result;
}
```

would not even compile.    The reason is that an integral type cannot be dereferenced as if it is a pointer.   The statement `return *result` will therefore not compile, let alone be executed.

In reality, converting an 8-bit unsigned integral value to a 32-bit unsigned integral type is perfectly simple.

```
UINT32 convU8toU32(UINT8 number)
{
   UINT32 result = number;
   return result;
}
```

or, even more simply,

```
UINT32 convU8toU32(UINT8 number)
{
   return number;
}
```

These rely on implicit conversions to 32-bit unsigned integral type.  Since a 32-bit unsigned integral type can exactly represent every value that an 8-bit unsigned integral type can, the conversion preserves value.    Conversion the other way (from 32-bit to 8-bit) potentially loses value.

If you want to avoid implicit conversions, simply do an explicit conversion, such as

```
UINT32 convU8toU32(UINT8 number)
{
    return (UINT32) number;    // C-style conversion - discouraged in C++
}
```

or

```
UINT32 convU8toU32(UINT8 number)
{
    return UINT32(number);
}
```

or (to really make it obvious to anyone looking, and easy to find when searching a source file)

```
UINT32 convU8toU32(UINT8 number)
{
    return static_cast<UINT32>(number);
}
```

Of course, a function isn't even needed

```
 UINT8 value8 = something();
 UINT32 value32 = value8;
```

will do instead of using this function.